# How to use FieldType.Long for String in elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

While i used spring-data-elasticsearch 2.1 and elasticserch 2.4 this worked:

```
@MultiField(
        mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed),
        otherFields = {@InnerField(suffix = "analyzed", store = true, type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "indexAnalyzer", searchAnalyzer = "searchAnalyzer")})
    private String parameterValue;
```

But when i upgraded spring-data-elasticsearch to 3.0 and elasticsearch to 5.6 i got:
**MapperParsingException**: No handler for type [Long] declared on field

How to fix this except creating another class attribute with type Long and copy parsed String value?

Is the reason behind this avoiding NumberFormatException for values that can't be parsed from String to Long?

**Edit:**
When i use:

```
@MultiField(
        mainField = @Field(store = true, type = FieldType.text, analyzer = "indexAnalyzer", searchAnalyzer = "searchAnalyzer"),
        otherFields = {@InnerField(suffix = "sort", type = FieldType.Long)})
    private String parameterValue;
```

i get this mapping:

```
"parameterValue": {
   "type": "text",
   "fields": {
      "sort": {
         "type": "long"
      }
   }
}
```

Which is wrong because analyzer and searchAnalyzer are not applied and settings file that contains custom "indexAnalyzer" and "searchAnalyzer" is correct and applied for other fields.

**EDIT-SOLUTION:**

This works:

```
@MultiField(
        mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.keyword),
        otherFields = {@InnerField(suffix = "sort", type = FieldType.Long),
            @InnerField(suffix = "analyzed", store = true, type = FieldType.text, indexAnalyzer = "indexAnalyzer", searchAnalyzer = "searchAnalyzer")})
    private String parameterValue;
```

and the mapping:

```
"parameterValue": {
   "type": "keyword",
   "fields": {
      "analyzed": {
         "type": "text",
         "analyzer": "indexAnalyzer",
         "search_analyzer": "searchAnalyzer"
      },
      "sort": {
         "type": "long"
      }
   }
}
```

My conclusion is that **when using spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0 and elasticsearch 5.6 we can't have custom analyzers in main field of the @MultiField**, and need to add another inner field. Also main field can’t be different than the attribute - if we have String attribute, main field must not be FieldType.Long but probably only text or keyword.

It's strange but for now this is the only working solution i found.